# Honeyd , не логирует действия

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть, kali-linux

по  лабораторной работе с  Honeyd  надо просмотреть как он работает.
Сеть в которой всё происходит : 192.168.1.0/24
Стоит на Ubuntu 12.04.5 lts
файл honeyd.conf:

```
create default
set default default tcp action block
set default default udp action block
set default default icmp action block

# Linux 2.4.x computer
create linux
set linux personality "Linux 2.4.16 - 2.4.18"
set linux default tcp action reset
set linux default udp action reset
add linux tcp port 21 "sh /usr/share/honeyd/scripts/unix/linux/ftp.sh"
add linux tcp port 25 "sh /usr/share/honeyd/scripts/unix/general/smtp.sh"
add linux tcp port 80 "sh /usr/share/honeyd/scripts/unix/linux/suse8.0/telnetd.sh"
set linux uptime 3284460
set linux ethernet "00:21:6a:b8:11:24"
bind 192.168.1.135 linux

# Windows computer
create winxp
set winxp personality "Microsoft Windows XP Professional SP1"
set winxp default tcp action reset
set winxp default udp action reset
set winxp default icmp action open
add winxp tcp port 80 "sh /usr/share/honeyd/scripts/unix/linux/suse8.0/telnetd.sh"
add winxp tcp port 23 "/etc/honeypot/scripts/telnet/faketelnet.pl"
add winxp tcp port 445 open
set winxp ethernet " 00:15:5d:0a:06:01"
set winxp uptime 3284460
bind 192.168.1.136 winxp
```

Так же прочла на 1 из форумов что надо было сменить значение  в файлах honeyd та farpd

```
/etc/default:
RUN="yes"
INTERFACE="eth0"
NETWORK="192.168.1.0/24"
```

Ввожу команду на стороне honeyd : `sudo honeyd -d -i eth0 -f /etc/honeypot/honeyd.conf 192.168.1.0/24 -l /tmp/honeypot.log`
Но при сканирование с другой машины ( скажем с 192.168.1.111) с помощью nmap на адрес 192.168.1.135 в логах honeypot ничего не пишет, так же на стороне с запуском нпама не выдает название системы при скане на её определение . И если в команде honeyd указывать только отмеченные адреса(192.168.1.135-192.168.1.136) то маска /32 , Что можно сделать чтобы все это исправить?